# After my question has been rigorously edited, I think the mechanism should be reviewed

Tags: discussion

[I have oepend a question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715208/composer-does-not-install-no-permission-for-creating-var-composer-phar-how/715336#715336):

The original question dealt mostly with permissions and reminded a problem with a program called composer only as a subtle issue that might possibly be associated with the permissions issue (just to sharpen the question). I asked the question as a total newbie in Linux and Ubuntu.

Someone have changed my question entirely including the title, to how he saw fit, and than answered on this other question a seemingly-sadistic, too much mocking answer, and in the covering of a honest technical answer. His answer even got a 1 dislike and I commented on it from my POV.

I really love this site, and I want to stay here, but this really gave me a bad taste. I have flagged the answer but no one seems to take care of this in the last hour or so (I guess the mods here are always on).

Please consider bringing my question to its original state and anything you would see fit with the answer; I think in any case the edit control should be re-examined in that context and I hope no one here will see this suggestion as audacity.

Comment: No, the mods here aren't always on, we have lives too :) Someone will get to reviewing it as soon as they have time. This is a farely large site and even with as many moderators as we have the queue is still fairly large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go back into your question and add the details that you've found out so far and keep going. If you feel part of it is wrong then just change it, it's your question. Obviously doing the `sS` instead of the `-sS` is something you probably realized afterwards. So try it again and post some clarifications as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Then I would just ignore the patronizing part and see what other answers you get.

The answer is pretty good if you chop off the first "mistake #1" paragraph and subsequent lecturing/snark. Linking to that banana stuff is just a veiled "LMGTFY" link, which we explicitly don't want here.

Also there's nothing wrong with you then creating a proper answer out of what you've learned with the right solution and just let community bury the one with bad attitude.